# scalike-jdbc - How to specify column alias in query?

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, scalikejdbc

I defined an object to help to convert result set into POJO.

```
  // an object, that help to map from query result to POJO,
  object Dummy extends SQLSyntaxSupport[Dummy] {
    override val tableName = "dummy"
    def apply(rs: WrappedResultSet) = new Dummy(
      rs.long("id"), rs.stringOpt("name"), rs.intOpt("size"), rs.jodaDateTime("create_date"))
  }
```

Then following code try to query from a table,

```
  /*** query - with condition - start ***/
  // use paste mode (:paste) on the Scala REPL
  val d = Dummy.syntax("d")
  val name = "hello"
  val helloDummyOpt: Option[Dummy] = withSQL {
    select.from(Dummy as d).where.eq(d.name, name).limit(1)
  }.map(rs => Dummy(rs)).single.apply()

  printf("hello dummy:\t%s\n", if(helloDummyOpt.isDefined) helloDummyOpt.get else "")
  /*** query - with condition - end ***/
```

From console, I can see the generated sql is:

```
select d.id as i_on_d, d.name as n_on_d, d.size as s_on_d, d.create_date as cd_on_d
from dummy d where d.name = 'hello' limit 1;
```

In order to make the convert work, need to change column alias in generated sql to remain as the original name in table, e.g `name` instead of `n_on_d`.

So, how to do that, thanks.

---

### @Update

The complete code is here:

```
package eric.scalikejdbc

import scalikejdbc._
import org.postgresql.Driver._
import org.joda.time._

/**
 * scalikejdbc hello.
 * @author eric
 * @date Jul 6, 2016 23:14:07 PM
 */
object ScalikeJdbcHello extends App {
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
  ConnectionPool.singleton("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sportslight", "postgres", "123456")

  implicit val session = AutoSession

  /*** query - parse as List of Map - start ***/
  // find rows, with limit 10000,
  val entities: List[Map[String, Any]] = sql"select * from dummy limit 10000".map(_.toMap).list.apply()
  printf("dummy count: %d\n", entities.size)
  /*** query - parse as List of Map - end ***/

  /*** query - parse as POJO - start ***/
  // define a POJO class,
  case class Dummy(id: Long, name: Option[String], size: Option[Int], createDate: DateTime)

  // an object, that help to map from query result to POJO,
  object Dummy extends SQLSyntaxSupport[Dummy] {
    override val tableName = "dummy"
    def apply(rs: WrappedResultSet) = new Dummy(
      rs.long("id"), rs.stringOpt("name"), rs.intOpt("size"), rs.jodaDateTime("create_date"))
  }

  // find top 10 rows,
  val dummyList: List[Dummy] = sql"select * from dummy limit 10".map(rs => Dummy(rs)).list.apply()

  var i = 0;
  printf("dummy top rows:\n")
  for (d <- dummyList) {
    printf("\t[%d] %s\n", i, d)
    i = i + 1
  }
  /*** query - parse as POJO - end ***/

  /*** query - with condition - start ***/
  // TODO ... specify column name in result,
  val d = Dummy.syntax("d")
  val name = "hello"
  val helloDummyOpt: Option[Dummy] = withSQL {
    select.from(Dummy as d).where.eq(d.name, name).limit(1)
  }.map(rs => Dummy(rs)).single.apply()

  printf("hello dummy:\t%s\n", if(helloDummyOpt.isDefined) helloDummyOpt.get else "")
  /*** query - with condition - end ***/
}
```

And here is the sql to create table & initialize data for `postgresql`:

```
/* table - dummy */
-- drop table
drop table if exists dummy;

-- create table
create table dummy (
    id serial8,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    size int not null,
    create_date timestamptz,
    primary key (id)
);

-- init data - dummy
insert into dummy(name, size, create_date) values
('test', 1, now()),
('hello', 1, now());
```

Comment: why do you worry about aliases? You should never see use them in your code as you work with Dummy object instead.

Comment: @Rumoku I updated the question, with more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select.from` calls `alias.result.*`. Calling `alias.*` simply returns  column names as-is.

```
scala> select(a.*).from(Article as a).toSQL.statement
res7: String = select a.id, a.title, a.body, a.created_at, a.updated_at from articles a

scala> select(a.result.*).from(Article as a).toSQL.statement
res8: String = select a.id as i_on_a, a.title as t_on_a, a.body as b_on_a, a.created_at as ca_on_a, a.updated_at as ua_on_a from articles a

scala> select.from(Article as a).toSQL.statement
res9: String = select a.id as i_on_a, a.title as t_on_a, a.body as b_on_a, a.created_at as ca_on_a, a.updated_at as ua_on_a from articles a
```

Comment: The first example fixed the code, as this: `val helloDummyOpt: Option[Dummy] = withSQL {
    select(d.*).from(Dummy as d).where.eq(d.name, name).limit(1)
  }.map(rs => Dummy(rs)).single.apply()`, but maybe the code example from `http://scalikejdbc.org/` the `First example` the final query start with `val alice:`, should also be adjusted in similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You're using half type safe DSL, half default API. You should choose one and proceed with it.

In case of TypeSafe DSL you should not use custom `SqlSyntaxSupport` implementations.

Instead of `.map(rs => Dummy(rs))` you should be able to operate with `d Dummy` object, defined in sql query.

```
  val d = Dummy.syntax("d")

  val helloDummyOpt: Option[Dummy] = withSQL {
    select.from(Dummy as d).where.eq(d.name, name).limit(1)
  }.single.apply()
```

Check TypeSafe DSL section for more examples: http://scalikejdbc.org

If you want to receive those auto-generated names, you should refer to them through object d:

```
 val d = Dummy.syntax("d")
d.id // = i_on_d
d.name // = n_on_d
d.create_date // = cd_on_d
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually the code is mimic from http://scalikejdbc.org/ the `First example` part. I tried your code, it says `Error:(51, 17) No extractor is specified. You have forgotten call #map(...) before #apply().
  }.single.apply()`. I have added the complete code to question can you modify base on that, to make it runnable?